# Is it possible (or advisable) for a method to recognize its caller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, enums

I'm developing a simple game where a player needs to roll a die and then "the computer" needs to do it.

I would like a `roll` method that performs slightly differently for each type of player.

It's currently set up with a `BOOL` parameter called `isPlayer` (vs. isComputer).  Players pass a TRUE value, computer a FALSE.  There's some `if` statements in the method that act accordingly.

This seems clunky to me. Is there a better way?

I was thinking of creating a `PlayerType` enum and each player would have a type but they would still need to pass the type to the method.  That or they could change a game variable to that type and the method could recognize that.

Any thoughts would be helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that seems fine and is a much-used and simple pattern.

A `BOOL` is fine all the time there are just two types of player (or behaviour) and then moving to an `enum` if the number of players extends beyond 2.

Alternatively there is polymorphism where the `roll` method behaves differently depending on the subclass that implements it.  This would require no parameters to be passed as the behaviour is *locked in* to the class.

Comment: Can you briefly sketch out how the roll method would recognize which subclass called it?

Comment: @MayNotBe What I meant was each subclass would *implement* the `roll` method differently.  When not using a polymorphic approach it's necessary to pass directions to the method, as you are currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

Passing an enum can be a good option.

Another one is to create a superclass called "Protagonist" (for eg.) implementing a `roll()` method and two other classes "Human" and "Player" inheriting from "Protagonist". This way, you can specify the behaviour for each kind of player.

```
//Protagonist.h (your superclass)
@interface Protagonist : NSObject

- (void)roll;

@end

//Player.h
#import "Protagonist.h"

@interface Player : Protagonist

@end

//Player.m
@implementation Player

- (void)roll {
    NSLog(@"I'm a real player");
    }

@end

//Computer.h
#import "Protagonist.h"

@interface Computer : Protagonist

@end

//Computer.m
@implementation Computer

- (void)roll {
    NSLog(@"I'm a computer");
}

@end

//ExternalController.m
Protagonist *computer = [Computer new];
[computer roll]; //"I'm a computer"

Protagonist *computer = [Player new];
[computer roll]; //"I'm a real player"
```

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C. It's best to provide answers in the relevant language.